# Changing the default AspNet tables to my own tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

I've got a situation like this. I have a web MVC application, which is doing an external authentication using Facebook. It's working fine, but I need to change the table, where the users are inserted. For example there's a table called AspNetUsers, I want to change it to my Users table. I've got this code in my IdentityModel.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        {
            public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
            {
                var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                return userIdentity;
            }
        }

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("Entities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
}
```

I've looked through all posts like that. For example I've tried to add a protected method called OnModelCreating , which was

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("PPP_Users");
}
```

but it was giving me error , saying that there are invalid columns.

Can anyone help me with this question please ?
Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Guys. I've created a new table with the same fields in it. And have changed some bits in the AspNetUserLogs table. As for me, it works well now.